# GA-100% pageviews are not being sent for page load sample

Tags: google-analytics

We have updated Google Analytics sampling rate to 100% for many partners.

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
```

However, for some partners, we observed that all pageviews are not set for page load sampling. In some cases, it is around 80%.

Is there any exact reason for this? Doesn't {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100} means all pageviews should be sent for page load sampling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you put the sampling rate to 100 you can still hit quota limits here (Site Speed processing quota limit).

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings#sampling_considerations

To measure all the site speed hits you can extract the values (different load times) via GTM and some custom javascript and send the values as dimensions or events.